# How do I create a sub-resource with spring dependencies @autowired with apache cxf

Tags: spring, cxf, jax-rs

I can't figure out how to get spring to autowire dependencies in a sub resource. I need to specify some request state to the sub resource. I'll also need access to cxf managed @Contexts.

If I have a class

```
@Path("/resource/")
public class Resource {
    @Autowired
    private dependency

    @Path("{id}/sub/")
    public getSub(@PathParam("id") String id){
      // I know this is not right. I could autowire subresource, but it needs
      // to be request scoped and I get errors about proxying request scoped bean
      // into singleton bean. 

      // I have also tried instantiating the subresource using ResourceContext 
      // but then Subresource's dependencies don't get injected
      return new Subresource(id);
    }
}
```

And another class

```
public class Subresource{

    @Context
    private UriInfo uriInfo;

    @Autowired
    private Dependency2 dependency2;

    private String id;
    public Subresource(String id){

    }
    @GET
    public Response get(){
       return Response.ok(id).build();
    }
}
```

How do I get the spring managed dependencies to be auto injected in the sub resources? How does the sub resource get access to CXF managed dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

I create factory bean to instantiate sub-resource:

```
public class SubResourceFactory {
    @Autowired
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireBeanFactory;

    public SubResource createBean(String parameter1, Parameter2 parameter2) {
        ... creating SubResource instance, setting parameters to it

        autowireBeanFactory.autowireBean(subResource);
        return (SubResource) autowireBeanFactory.initializeBean(subResource, "subResource");
    }
}
```

[AutowireCapableBeanFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html) allows to init bean created outside of Spring Context and inject any Spring beans to it.
SubResourceFactory is instantiated as Spring singleton bean in my project and injected in Root Resource, so i can use it like this:

```
@Resource
private SubResourceFactory subResourceFactory;

@Override
public SubResource getInfoFromSubResource(String parameter1) {
    Parameter2 parameter2 = parameter2StoreService.getParameter2(parameter1);
    return subResourceFactory.createBean(parameter1, parameter2);
}
```

But this subResource is managed only by Spring, so You can inject only Spring beans, You can not inject CXF-RS @Context beans.
There must be a way to do same thing to allow Spring and CXF-RS injections with [ResourceContext](http://blogs.steeplesoft.com/posts/2013/04/04/initializing-jax-rs-sub-resources/), but I can see now, that it injects only CXF-RS beans, no Spring at all.